# How can I optimize this majority vote

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, iterable

I have the following code to do a majority vote for data in a dataframe:

```
def vote(df, systems):
    test = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['begin', 'end', 'case', 'system'])
    n = int(len(systems)/2)
    data = []
        
    for row in test.itertuples():
        # get all matches
        fx = test.loc[(test.begin == row.begin) & (test.end == row.end) & (test.case == row.case)]
        fx = fx.loc[fx.system.isin(systems)]

        # keep if in a majority of systems   
        if len(set(fx.system.tolist())) > n:
            data.append(fx)
             
    out = pd.concat(data, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
    out = out.drop_duplicates(subset=['begin', 'end', 'case'])
    
    return out[['begin', 'end', 'case']]
```

The data look like:

```
systems = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

df = begin,end,system,case
0,9,A,0365
10,14,A,0365
10,14,B,0365
10,14,C,0365
28,37,A,0366
38,42,A,0366
38,42,B,0366
53,69,C,0366
56,60,B,0366
56,60,C,0366
56,69,D,0366
64,69,E,0366
83,86,B,0367
```

The expected output should be:

```
out = begin,end,case
    10,14,0365
    56,69,0366
```

IOW, if desired elements `begin, end, case` appear in a majority of systems, we accumulate them and return them as a dataframe.

The algorithm works perfectly fine, but since there are hundreds of thousands of rows in it, this is taking quite a while to process.

One optimization I can think of, but am unsure of how to implement is in the `itertuples` iteration: If, for the first instance of a filter set `begin, end, case` there are matches in

```
fx = test.loc[(test.begin == row.begin) & (test.end == row.end) & (test.case == df.case) & (fx.system.isin(systems))]
```

then, it would be beneficial to not iterate over the other rows in the `itertuples` iterable that match on this filter. For example, for the first instance of `10,14,A,0365` there is no need to check the next two rows, since they've already been evaluated. However, since the iterable is already fixed, there is no way to skip these of which I can think.

Comment: i think this question is more suited to [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pandas)

Comment: Thanks, I was debating whether to post it there.

Comment: 1 more thing, the function doesnot work on the dummy data shared. kindly fix it :) `fx.system.isin(systems))` maybe

Comment: can you rpovide little more data, which may have different systems mentioned than current dtaa ? just want to test solution on that

Answer (score 0):

moving this to codereview... (don't want to delete it and lose reputation points!)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are looking for,

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

#Preprocessing(ignore)
data = StringIO('''
0,9,A,0365
10,14,A,0365
10,14,B,0365
10,14,C,0365
28,37,A,0366
38,42,A,0366
38,42,B,0366
53,69,C,0366
56,60,B,0366
56,60,C,0366
56,69,D,0366
64,69,E,0366
83,86,B,0367
''')

systems = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
df = pd.read_csv(data,names=['begin','end','system','case'])

df_test = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['begin', 'end', 'case', 'system'])[df['system'].isin(systems)]
n = int(len(systems)/2)

out = df_test.groupby(['begin']).agg({
    'end':'max',
    'case':'max',
    'system': 'count'
}).reset_index()

out[out['system'] > n][['begin', 'end', 'case']]
```

Output:

```
begin   end case
1   10  14  365
5   56  69  366
```